# Só consigo dar output a um registo da database. Como é que dou output a todos os registos que tenho na base de dados?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PAPEntities db = new PAPEntities();
    MoviesData movie = db.MoviesData.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MovieID == 1);

    List<MovieViewModels> MovieVM = new List<MovieViewModels>
    {
        new MovieViewModels 
        {
            MovieID = movie.MovieID,
            MovieName = movie.MovieName,
            MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
            MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
            MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
            MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
        }
    };

    return View(MovieVM);
}
```

Código da view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@item.MovieName</td>
    <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
    <td>@item.MovieYear
    <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: Pô, o código tá especificando pra obter só um registro!

Comment: A sério? O que tenho de mudar para obter todos os registros?

Comment: Quando estiver programando, procure pesquisar e entender o que faz cada linha do seu código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `SingleOrDefault` serve justamente para obter apenas um registro de acordo com o predicado passado por parâmetro.

Você precisa remover a chamada para este método.

```
MoviesData[] movies = db.MoviesData.ToArray();
```

O `ToArray` serve para realizar a consulta no banco e enumerar tudo em memória. Isso poderia ser postergado, mas o método `Select` não permite criar uma instância de alguma classe que não seja um modelo do EF — no caso de LINQ To Entities, pra deixar claro.

E depois fazer o mapeamento para cada item

```
movies.Select(m => new MovieViewModels
{
    MovieID = movie.MovieID,
    MovieName = movie.MovieName,
    MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
    MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
    MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
    MovieYear = movie.MovieYear        
});
```